# How to use both & and | operators in a pandas .loc() funcition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a question regarding a complex .loc I'd like to run on my df to mutate a new column. Let's say I have the following df:

```
    x   y   z
0   1   0   2
1   0   0   0
2   1   1   2
3   0   0   0
4   1   1   2
5   0   0   2
6   1   1   0
7   0   0   2
```

And I want to use both an `&` and a `|` in my .loc. I know very well how to use one or the other, but a certain task I'm trying to complete involves the use of both. Basically, I want to find the rows that meet the following condition:

x *or* y = 1 *and* z = 2

and make a new column that consists of a `1` if these conditions are met, and a `0` if they aren't. Like so:

```
    x   y   z  test   
0   1   0   2   1
1   0   0   0   0
2   1   1   2   1
3   0   0   0   0
4   1   1   2   1
5   0   0   2   0
6   1   1   0   0
7   0   0   2   0
```

Again, I know how to run a loc consisting of one or the other, but not both `&` and `|`. Before posting, I tried the following code out to no avail:

```
df['test'] = 0
df.loc[((df['x'] == 1) | (df['y'] == 1)) & (df['z'] == 2),'test'] = 1
```

I thought I was super clever by including an extra set of () around the | condition, but alas it did not work. However, this code does work just fine when I'm using one operator or the other, just not both. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The sample code you supplied produces your expected output for me - what is the output you're getting?

Comment: You have the correct approach here.  That should work as planned.

Comment: You are right... I had an error in my code that I guess I unknowingly fixed when typing it out for this question. Sorry about that!! @ScottBoston

Comment: Maybe you should also get rid of .loc, just write an expression for the index, that takes few parenthesis out.